# Laravel Pagination not working in Blade file with Tailwind CSS

Tags: laravel, pagination, tailwind-css

I'm trying to use Laravel pagination. The issue is that when I use the links() method in the Blade file, it gives an error. For example, when I use the URL "http://127.0.0.1:8000/tournaments?page=3," it works fine, but it gives an error in the Blade file, as explained below.

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    return view('front.tournaments', [
        'seriesdata' => $this->tournamentList()
    ]);
}

public function tournamentList()
{
    return Series::leftJoin('team_squads as ts', 'ts.id_series', 'series.id')
        ->leftJoin('series_team_squads as sts', 'sts.id_series', 'series.id')
        ->leftJoin('admins as a', 'a.adminable_id', 'series.id')
        ->where('series.lang', 'en')
        ->orderBy('series.id', 'asc')
        ->groupBy('series.id')
        ->select('series.*')
        ->paginate(10)
        ->append([
            'logo_url',
            'location'
        ]);
}
```

**Blade**

```
@foreach($seriesdata as $series)
<div class="flex flex-inline xs:flex-col sm:flex-row">
    <div class="w-full border-b">
        <div class="flex justify-center items-start">
            <div class="py-2 mx-auto sm:bg-white xs:bg-white  w-full">
                <a href="{{ url('tournaments/').'/'.$series->url.'/'.$series->id }}" class="flex">
                    <div class="grid grid-rows-1 grid-flow-col gap-1">
                        <div class="row-span-1 col-span-2">
                            <img src="{{ $series->logo_url }}" alt="avatar" class="object-cover w-12 h-12 mx-4">
                        </div>
                        <div class="row-span-1 col-span-2">
                            <h1 class="font-bold text-lg">{{ $series->name }}</h1>
                            <p class="uppercase font-light text-sm text-grey">{{ $series->location->address }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
{{ $seriesdata->links() }}
```

**Error**
[image]

Comment: Always return `->paginate(xxxx)` and never add anything else after that method call. `->paginate` should be the last thing you call and return **ALWAYS**, so if you want to add anything else, do it before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `append()` method is blocking pagination in blade. Try to remove it from `tournamentList()` in controller.

---

When you do `->append()` after the `->paginate()`, you are transforming what `->paginate()` returns (basically a `LenghtAwarePaginator`) into a `Collection`, and `Collection` does not have a `->links()` method. You can see this as the error shows you are trying to call `links` method in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`, that is how I know what `->append()` is returning.